# Alternative to this line of HTTP Code

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-7, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I'm porting some code to Windows Phone 7. This line doesn't seem to work:

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

I have been trying to find an answer to it but all I can find is refrences to async methods which I have never used before. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work." Are there error messages? Is nothing returned? Does it not compile?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 only supports asynchronous operations when it comes to HTTP requests.

Instead, you should use `httpRequest.BeginGetResponse()` (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)) and manipulate the response data in the async callback.

I implemented this pattern when I was working on the Flickr API for WP7. You can see a real-world example of async HTTP request handling [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/flickr-api-windows-phone-7-%E2%80%93-7).

Answer (score 4):

I'll go ahead and assume you're writing a Silverlight application for Windows Phone 7; if that's the case:

Silverlight doesn't support the use of synchronous web requests. What you have to do is use the [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse%28VS.95%29.aspx) method, and pass it a function delegate for what you want to do with the response once it's been retrieved. MSDN has an excellent code example at the bottom of the page that shows how to use the asynchronous methods.